# not able to read from dynamic text box created in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am new to dotnet and am just trying out to add a row of text boxes for a grid view DYNAMICALLY.

On load of the page the grid view will be loaded with data as read only.

on clicking edit button, 2nd row will be loaded with text boxes. i succeeded till here. now on entering some data on these text boxes am not able to read the value back in my c# code.

here is my code snippet. can anyone please help me in this.

ASP code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="justGrid._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <br />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>

    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="170px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="edit" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="save" />
    <br />

</asp:Content>
```

C# code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                staticTable();
            }
            bindGrid();
        }
        protected void staticTable()
        {
            string[] NamesArray = new string[] { "RAM", "SAM", "TOM", "JERRY" };
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ds.Tables.Add();
            dt.Columns.Add("Names", typeof(string));
            for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
            {

                dt.Columns.Add("" + j, typeof(string));

            }
            foreach (string l in NamesArray)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(l);
            }
            dt.Rows[0][1] = "S";
            dt.Rows[0][2] = "P";
            dt.Rows[0][5] = "P";
            dt.Rows[1][2] = "S";
            dt.Rows[1][4] = "P";
            dt.Rows[2][3] = "S";
            dt.Rows[3][1] = "U";
            dt.Rows[3][5] = "P";

            ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            // GridView1.DataBind();

        }
        protected void bindGrid()
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];

            GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= 5; k++)
            {
                TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
                tb1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                tb1.Width = 15;

                tb1.ID = "TBID" + k;
                tb1.Text = GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[k].Text.Trim().Replace("&nbsp;", string.Empty);

                GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[k].Controls.Add(tb1);
            }
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].FindControl("TBID1");
            TextBox1.Text = box1.Text;
        }

    }
```

Note: for testing purpose alone..am trying to display the 2nd row 1st column value in textbox.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{    
    TextBox box1 = row.FindControl("TBID") as TextBox;
    if (box1 != null)
    {
        string value = box1.Text;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Anthony thanks for your reply...I tried this too. but still not able to read the textbox value.